# Peewee can't connect to MySQL on Remote Host

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I'm using Python 3.5 + Spyder 2 (from Anaconda) on Windows 10. I have an Ubuntu 16.04 desktop machine which is running a MySQL server on a LAN addressable IP. PhpMyAdmin works fine with this remote server. However, every time I attempt to connect to this server from my Windows 10 Spyder I get the following error:

`OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'10.0.0.30' (using password: YES)")`

The command I'm using is:

```
import os
from peewee import *
from playhouse.db_url import connect

db = MySQLDatabase('test', host="10.0.0.80", port=3306, user='root', passwd='*********')
db.connect()
```

The IP of the machine I'm using to make the call is 10.0.0.30 shown in the Error. I originally tried it before the "test" db existed. Then I created the "test" db using PhpMyAdmin. I then tested again. Same error. I have created a table in the "test" db via PhpMyAdmin to confirm that root has the appropriate privileges (which wasn't really a question but I wanted confirm).

I have downloaded and installed what I could find via several StackOverflow questions prior to posting this question. I have also rebooted to make sure that any new drivers and such that I installed were actually up and running.

Note my issue is not the same as this one:
[Peewee - Can't connect to MySQL server on host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30939688/peewee-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-host)

My connection error shows that despite using the host argument and setting it to "10.0.0.80" that peewee is still trying to connect to 10.0.0.30. IP 10.0.0.30 is the Windows machine I'm running peewee from while 10.0.0.80 is the machine I'm attempting to connect to.

TIA

Comment: check your database = mysql, table = user, is there a record in this table: User = root, Host = 10.0.0.80 ?

Comment: No, there isn't. I don't remember ever having to do this in previous versions of Ubuntu and MySQL.

Comment: I have added root with host 10.0.0.80 to the table but it didn't change the outcome. I have restarted the mysql server as well.

Comment: The error is correct, it's reporting the client user (on 10.0.0.30) was denied access. Is the password really right?

Comment: so when you try to connect manually via `mysql` command in a shell, does it work?

Comment: @Keith, The password was correct. But your comment reminded me of a weird issue I'm had with PhpMyAdmin in the past. The issue was that the user would be created but the password would not take for some reason. Then I would go in and reset it... Voila it worked. Same happened here. I double checked the password and then set it the string from the call. All is good now...